# Query all ids not having a particular value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looking like this:

```
user_id    group_id
   1          1
   1          2
   1          3
   1          4
   2          1
   2          2
   3          3
   3          4
   4          3
   4          4
```

How can I query all user_id which are not in group 1. In this example, the result is 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `Group BY` and `Having` clause

```
select user_id 
from yourtable 
group by user_id 
having count(case when group_id = 1 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: This way is nice way

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it with a left join:

```
select distinct user_id
from a_table_you_did_not_name base
left join a_table_you_did_not_name g1 on base.user_id = g1.user_id and g1.group_id = 1
where g1.user_id is null
```

Here you do a left join and then "look" for things that did not join.  Since the join requires the existence of group_id = 1 this will give required results.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS operator and dependend subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   Select * FROM Table t1
   WHERE t1.user_id = t.user_id
     AND t1.group_id = 1
)
```

You can also use NOT IN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM Table t
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT user_id FROM table
   WHERE group_id = 1
)
```